# Render stereoscopic image on 3d tablet from processing android

Tags: android, processing, stereo-3d

i have ordered a [commander3d tablet](http://www.commander3d.com/), which makes it possible to see 3d images without glasses. I assumed it has some micro lenes which direct every second row to the right and the others to the left eye. Thus i thought, i would be possible to draw 2 overlayed images in processing android in a way, that a 3d effect is created.
Now i realized, that this does not work. It seems the 3d effect is not always turned on and needs to be initialized. Maybe it is a hardware thing. Does anybody know anything about this? Any hint would be great.
I also found this SDK for the tablet [sdeck.org](http://www.sdeck.org/), which is for openGL ES 2. But to be honest, if somehow possible I would prefer not to go into this, but instead work with processing for android. Any help is highly appreciated! thank you!
best
Markus